# Proxy doesn't work when running WSO2 as a Windows Service

Tags: wso2, vfs, yajsw, wso2-esb

I have a proxy which implements a VFS Transport.

- If I run carbon_home/wso2services.bat the proxy **works**.
- If I start wso2 as a windows service it **doesn't** but I am still **able** to access the Management Console.

  - VFS seems not working. The file is not scanned.

Should I need to add something to the wrapper.conf ? (C:\yajsw-beta-12.04\conf)

Here my wrapper.conf file

```
#********************************************************************
# working directory
#********************************************************************
wrapper.working.dir=${carbon_home}\\
# Java Main class. 
# YAJSW: default is "org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain"
# DO NOT SET THIS PROPERTY UNLESS YOU HAVE YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION
# wrapper.java.mainclass=
#********************************************************************
# tmp folder
# yajsw creates temporary files named in_.. out_.. err_.. jna..
# per default these are placed in jna.tmpdir.
# jna.tmpdir is set in setenv batch file to <yajsw>/tmp
#********************************************************************
wrapper.tmp.path = ${jna_tmpdir}
#********************************************************************
# Application main class or native executable
# One of the following properties MUST be defined
#********************************************************************
# Java Application main class
wrapper.java.app.mainclass=org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=${wrapper_home}\/log\/wrapper.log
# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
#wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM
# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
#wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling by size.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kB) or
#  'm' (mB) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
# If wrapper.logfile does not contain the string ROLLNUM it will be automatically added as suffix of the file name
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m
# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title="WSO2 Carbon"
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Service and Posix Daemon Properties
#********************************************************************
# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name="WSO2CARBON"
# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname="WSO2 Carbon"
# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description="Carbon Kernel"
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper System Tray Properties
#********************************************************************
# enable system tray
wrapper.tray = true
# TCP/IP port. If none is defined multicast discovery is used to find the port
# Set the port in case multicast is not possible.
wrapper.tray.port = 15002
#********************************************************************
# Exit Code Properties
# Restart on non zero exit code
#********************************************************************
wrapper.on_exit.0=SHUTDOWN
wrapper.on_exit.default=RESTART
#********************************************************************
# Trigger actions on console output
#********************************************************************
# On Exception show message in system tray
wrapper.filter.trigger.0=Exception
wrapper.filter.script.0=scripts\/trayMessage.gv
wrapper.filter.script.0.args=Exception
#********************************************************************
# genConfig: further Properties generated by genConfig
#********************************************************************
placeHolderSoGenPropsComeHere=
wrapper.java.command = ${java_home}\\bin\\java
wrapper.java.classpath.1 = ${java_home}\\lib\\tools.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2 = ${carbon_home}\\bin\\*.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.1 = org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
wrapper.app.parameter.2 = RUN
wrapper.java.additional.1 = -Xbootclasspath\/a:${carbon_home}\\lib\\xboot\\*.jar
wrapper.java.additional.2 = -Xms256m
wrapper.java.additional.3 = -Xmx1024m
wrapper.java.additional.4 = -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
wrapper.java.additional.5 = -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
wrapper.java.additional.6 = -XX:HeapDumpPath=${carbon_home}\\repository\\logs\\heap-dump.hprof
wrapper.java.additional.7 = -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.8 = -Djava.endorsed.dirs=${carbon_home}\\lib\\endorsed;${java_home}\\jre\\lib\\endorsed
wrapper.java.additional.9 = -Dcarbon.registry.root=\/
wrapper.java.additional.10 = -Dcarbon.home=${carbon_home}
wrapper.java.additional.11 = -Dwso2.server.standalone=true
wrapper.java.additional.12 = -Djava.command=${java_home}\\bin\\java
wrapper.java.additional.13 = -Djava.io.tmpdir=${carbon_home}\\tmp
wrapper.java.additional.14 = -Dcatalina.base=${carbon_home}\\lib\\tomcat
wrapper.java.additional.15 = -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\tomcat\\tomcat-log.properties
wrapper.java.additional.16 = -Dcarbon.config.dir.path=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf
wrapper.java.additional.17 = -Dcarbon.logs.path=${carbon_home}\\repository\\logs
wrapper.java.additional.18 = -Dcomponents.repo=${carbon_home}\\repository\\components\\plugins
wrapper.java.additional.19 = -Dconf.location=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf
wrapper.java.additional.20 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.file=${carbon_home}\\lib\\transactions.properties
wrapper.java.additional.21 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.hide_init_file_path=true
wrapper.java.additional.22 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true
wrapper.java.additional.23 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication=simple
wrapper.java.additional.24 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=3000
wrapper.java.additional.25 = -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dwso2.carbon.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\carbon.xml
wrapper.java.additional.27 = -Dwso2.registry.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\registry.xml
wrapper.java.additional.28 = -Dwso2.user.mgt.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\user-mgt.xml
wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dwso2.transports.xml=${carbon_home}\\repository\\conf\\mgt-transports.xml
wrapper.java.additional.31 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
wrapper.java.additional.33 = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Comment: When you say your proxy doesn't work, what happens exactly (don't scan, exceptions in wso2 logs) ?

Comment: Do not scan. Seems vfs transport doesn't work. I'm going to edit.

Answer (score 2):

To be closer to wso2server.bat, we have changed this part in wrapper.conf :

```
#wrapper.java.classpath.1 = ${java_home}\\lib\\tools.jar
#wrapper.java.classpath.2 = ${carbon_home}\\bin\\*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.1 = ${carbon_home}\\lib
wrapper.java.classpath.2 = ${java_home}\\lib\\tools.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3 = ${carbon_home}\\bin\\org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap-4.2.0.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4 = ${carbon_home}\\bin\\tcpmon-1.0.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.5 = ${carbon_home}\\bin\\tomcat-juli-7.0.34.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.6 = ${carbon_home}\\lib\\commons-lang-2.6.0.wso2v1.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.7 = ${carbon_home}\\bin\\*.jar
```

Not sure this is a solution for your problem, but VFS proxy are working in our ESB 4.8.1 installed as a windows service with this conf : tell me if it works for your.

Comment: Suddenly everything began to work. I don't know what happend. Trying to find out.

Comment: Indeed @Jean-Michel =)